# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I am trying to navigate to a new screen by pressing the "Process Order" Button but I keep getting the error **[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value**. I am not sure where exactly the error is happening.

I've been struggling with the for a while now. What could be the issue here?

```
class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/cart-screen';

  @override
  State<CartScreen> createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;  

  final TextEditingController deliveryNoteController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return isLoading
        ? const LoadingSpinner()
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              elevation: 0,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
              title: const Text(
                'Order Summary',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            body: cart.totalAmount <= 0
                ? const EmptyCartScreen()
                : SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('users')
                                  .doc(user!.uid)
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return const Text(
                                      'Oops, something went wrong.');
                                }
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return const LoadingSpinner();
                                }
                                DocumentSnapshot? doc = snapshot.data;
                                return Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    ListView.builder(
                                      physics:
                                          const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                      itemCount: cart.items.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, i) => CartItem(
                                        cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                                        cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                                        cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                                        cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                                        cart.items.values
                                            .toList()[i]
                                            .title
                                            .toString(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        const Text(
                                          'Delivery Address',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            fontSize: 16.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const Spacer(),
                                        TextButton(
                                          child: const Text('Edit'),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            showModalBottomSheet(
                                              context: context,
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  horizontal: 20.0,
                                                  vertical: 30.0,
                                                ),
                                                child: EditDeliveryInfoForm(),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        ListTile(
                                          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
                                          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                              horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
                                          leading: const Icon(
                                              Ionicons.location_outline),
                                          title: Text(doc!['address']),
                                        ),
                                        ListTile(
                                          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
                                          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                              horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
                                          leading: const Icon(
                                              Ionicons.person_outline),
                                          title: Text(doc['name']),
                                        ),
                                        ListTile(
                                          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
                                          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                              horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
                                          leading:
                                              const Icon(Ionicons.call_outline),
                                          title: Text(doc['phoneNumber']),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10.0,
                                        ),
                                        TextField(
                                          controller: deliveryNoteController,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: 'Delivery note',
                                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                                width: 1.6,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors
                                                    .lightBlueAccent.shade700,
                                                width: 1.6,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 12.0,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    const Divider(
                                      thickness: 1.2,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text(
                                            'Total Due',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'R${cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 22,
                                                letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      child: const Center(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 15.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Process Order',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        try {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = true;
                                          });
                                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                              .collection('orders')
                                              .add({
                                            'date': DateTime.now(),
                                            'order': cart.items.values
                                                .map((prod) =>
                                                    '${prod.title}, ${prod.quantity}')
                                                .join(";")
                                                .toString(),
                                            'total': cart.totalAmount
                                                .toStringAsFixed(2),
                                          });
                                          Navigator.of(context)
                                              .pushReplacementNamed(
                                                  OrderSuccess.routeName);

                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = false;
                                          });

                                          cart.clearCart();
                                        } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
                                          print(e.toString());
                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = false;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The null check operator is the `!` you use to tell Dart that you are certain that the preceding variable is not null.  If you're wrong (and it is null) you'll get this error.  There are two places where you could get this error in your code.

In your code, you have `final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` and it is not a given that this is not null, yet you use the null check operator in the statement `.doc(user!.uid)` which will throw the error if `user` is null.

Likewise, you set the variable `doc` using `DocumentSnapshot? doc = snapshot.data` (clearly a variable that can be null) and use the null check operator in `title: Text(doc!['address'])`, which could also generate this error.

If you variable *can* be null, then you have to check for that possibility using an `if... then` construct or using null-aware operators like `?` and `??`.  Only if you can statically prove that a nullable variable *cannot ever* be null at a certain point of your code can you forego that check and use the null-check operator `!`.

Comment: Thanks @Bram, I've replaced all the null check operators with the null-aware operators. However I'm still getting the same error

Comment: If the error actually happens inside the `Navigator.of(context)...` statement (as your screenshot suggests) then perhaps you have not set up your MaterialApp above the widget correctly (the Navigator needs a `Router`, and a `Router` is created by a `MaterialApp` or a `WidgetsApp`).

Comment: I've just made sure that all my routes are properly configured. What is weird is that when I remove the isLoading ? LoadingSpinner  condition around the scaffold its working. what could possible be the issue? @Bram

Comment: I suspect that is because without a Scaffold (when isLoading is true) the Router and therefore the Navigator is not set up properly.

Comment: @Bram Neither your answer nor your comments are providing any value rather than misleading the question asker.